# Checking posted value against array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am using A MVC framework (CodeIgniter). In my view, I have two arrays one for regular reports, and one for administrative reports :

```
 <div id="queries">

        <center><strong>Report Generator</strong></center>
<br />

<?php 
    $performance = array(
        '' => 'Click Here',
        '1' => 'Student Total Wait',
        '2' => 'Counselor Performance Per Session',
        '3' => 'Average Counselor Performance',
    );

    $admin = array(
        '' => 'Click Here',
        '4' => 'Reasons For Visit',
        '5' => 'Aid Years',
    );

    echo form_open('reports_controller/generate');
    echo "<p><strong>Performance Reports</strong></p>";
    echo form_dropdown('performance', $performance); 
    echo "<p><strong>Administrative Reports</strong></p>";
    echo form_dropdown('admin', $admin);

    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo form_submit('submit', 'Generate Report');
?>

</div>
```

All those two arrays do are populated the drop downs.

Now my problem comes when it actually gets posted to the controller. In my controller I have a foreach loop to check if the posted values are present, if it is then I want that to pull the model (sql query) dynamically based on what the user has chosen.

controller :

```
class Reports_controller extends MY_logincontroller {

function generate() {
    $this -> load -> model('reports_model');
    $reportsfunction = array('1' => 'studenttotalwait()', '2' => 'counselorperformance()', '3' => 'avgperformance()', '4' => 'reasons()', '5' => 'aidyears()', );
    foreach ($reportsfunction as $model_function) {
        $data['returns'] = $this -> reports_model -> $model_function;
        $data['main_content'] = 'reports/generate';
        $this -> load -> view('includes/js/js_template', $data);
    }
}
```

My question is now how I do I actually dynamically load the view that corresponds to that field sets in the that are being queried in the model? I feel confident of how my controller array  is working. I have yet to take Comp. Science 1 so I've been learning php in a misinformed manner.

I hope this is a proper question to ask.

Edit :

I can hard code to see if 1 is the posted value then output such and such view with this model data, but I want to save up on the work and learn a lot while doing the project. - Selfish - sorry.

Comment: I thing you're doing it the hardest way, instead of doing that, why don't you do a switch case

Comment: aaahhhhhhh...... dam.. that actually sounds a lot easier... alright. I'll update answer when I am done with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function generate() {
        $this -> load -> model('reports_model');
        $performance = $this -> input -> post('performance');
        $admin = $this -> input -> post('admin');
        if (!empty($performance) || !empty($admin)) {

            if ($this -> input -> post('performance') == '1') {
                $data['totalwait'] = $this -> reports_model -> studenttotalwait();
                $data['main_content'] = 'reports/tables/1';
                $this -> load -> view('includes/js/js_template', $data);
            }

            if ($this -> input -> post('performance') == '2') {
                $data['performance'] = $this -> reports_model -> counselorperformance();
                $data['main_content'] = 'reports/tables/2';
                $this -> load -> view('includes/js/js_template', $data);
            }

            if ($this -> input -> post('performance') == '3') {
                $data['avgperformance'] = $this -> reports_model -> avgperformance();
                $data['main_content'] = 'reports/tables/3';
                $this -> load -> view('includes/js/js_template', $data);
            }

            if ($this -> input -> post('admin') == '4') {
                $data['reasons'] = $this -> reports_model -> reasons();
                $data['main_content'] = 'reports/tables/4';
                $this -> load -> view('includes/js/js_template', $data);
            }

            if ($this -> input -> post('admin') == '5') {
                $data['avgperformance'] = $this -> reports_model -> aidyears();
                $data['main_content'] = 'reports/tables/5';
                $this -> load -> view('includes/js/js_template', $data);
            }

        } else {
            $this -> session -> set_flashdata('reports', 'Please choose a report');
            redirect('staff_controller/reports', 'location');
        }
    }
```

I ended up using if else statements, I worked with Switch Case, but I looked into the speed and there are a lot of arguments between using switch case and if else elseif... I stuck with old reliable if else.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter version. Instead doing all the work in a single function, do a breakdown:

```
function generate()
{
    $this -> load -> model('reports_model');
    $performance = $this -> input -> post('performance');
    $admin = $this -> input -> post('admin');

    if (!empty($performance) || !empty($admin))
    {
        $data = $this->_data($performance);
        $data['main_content'] = 'reports/tables/'.$performance;
        $this -> load -> view('includes/js/js_template', $data);
    } 
    else
    {
        $this -> session -> set_flashdata('reports', 'Please choose a report');
        redirect('staff_controller/reports', 'location');
    }

}

// saves the day
function _data($performance = 0)
{
    $this -> load -> model('reports_model');

    if(!isset($data[$performance]))
    {
        return FALSE;
    };

    $data = array(
        1 => array(
                 'totalwait' => $this -> reports_model -> studenttotalwait()
             ),
        2 => array(
                 'performance' => $this -> reports_model -> counselorperformance()
             ),
        3 => array(
                 'avgperformance' => $this -> reports_model -> avgperformance()
             ),
        4 => array(
                 'reasons' => $this -> reports_model -> reasons()
             ),
        5 => array(
                 'avgperformance' => $this -> reports_model -> aidyears()
             )
    );
    return $data[$performance];
}
```

This method breaks code redundancy which, at the same time, provides code re-usability